# Rails ActiveRecord builds wrong foreign key if there are two belongs_to relationships to same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Using Rails 3.2.3, I have User and Message models. Each message is owned by a user, and each message has an optional from_user field that also takes a user.id.

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, :foreign_key => "owner_id",     :inverse_of => :owner
  has_many :messages, :foreign_key => "from_user_id", :inverse_of => :from_user
end
```

**app/models/message.rb**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :messages
  validates  :owner, :presence => true   # Every message must have an owner_id

  belongs_to :from_user, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :messages
end
```

The problem I'm seeing is with the `.build` method. The main reason to use `.build` is to instantiate a (possibly protected) foreign key, right?  (See the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-collection-build) on Active Record associations:  "the link through their foreign key will be created.")  However when I run

```
@message = @user.messages.build(<accessible attributes>)
```

I find that it is filling in the optional `from_user` and *not* the mandatory `owner`.

Is there some way to control which foreign key `.build` fills in?  Or do I need to just use `.new` and assign all foreign keys manually?

```
@message = Message.new(<accessible attributes>)
@message.owner = @user
@message.from_user = @another_user
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActiveRecord doesnt like that you have 2 associations with the same name. You're going to have to change the association names. This means that you will also have to supply the `class_name` attibute. Maybe something like:

```
has_many :owner_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => "owner_id",     :inverse_of => :owner
has_many :user_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => "from_user_id", :inverse_of => :from_user
```

Comment: Thanks, spot on. And then it's `@user.owner_messages.build(<accessible attributes>)` to build.  I wonder why, if Rails requires unique association names, it doesn't complain when they're not unique?  Apparently it just uses the last definition--if I had happened to define `has_many :messages, :foreign_key => "owner_id"` second, I never would have seen this.

Comment: Just realized that the `:inverse_of` names must change in the `belongs_to` lines.   `belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :owner_messages` and `belongs_to :from_user, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :user_messages`.